# Optimal method of displaying a lot of data when hovering over icons

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, performance

I'm building a website that is going to show a lot of data when hovering over icons (about 2000 icons with different data), and I'm having doubts about what the best approach to do this is.

For a better idea of what I'm doing, I made a very short video - https://i.imgur.com/Ra2De3v.mp4

I'm currently storing all data in a huge PHP array and caching (pre-formatting) the HTML code that is going to be displayed on hover. Here's a snippet of what this looks like for the first icon as shown in the video:

custom_data.php:

```php
'c1' => 
  array (
    'custom_description_raw' => '{{stat|tears+}} +0.7 tears.',
    'costume' => 'Collectible_The_Sad_Onion_appearance.webp',
    'keywords' => 'tears',
    'pools' => 'treasure 1.0, greedTreasure 1.0, craneGame 1.0',
    'tags' => 'summonable tearsup offensive',
    'transformations-text' => '',
    'mod' => '!vanilla',
    'id' => 'c1',
    'type' => 'passive',
    'gfx' => '/IsaacGuru/core/data/!vanilla/collectibles/collectibles_001_thesadonion.webp',
    'achievement' => '',
    'cache' => 'firedelay',
    'maxcharges' => '',
    'chargetype' => '',
    'cooldown' => '',
    'hidden' => false,
    'id-raw' => '1',
    'name_key' => 'THE_SAD_ONION_NAME',
    'description_key' => 'THE_SAD_ONION_DESCRIPTION',
    'type_full' => 'Passive item',
    'name' => 'The Sad Onion',
    'description' => 'Tears up',
    'quality' => '3',
    'custom_description' => '<span class=\'sprite-block stat-spritesheet\' style=\'--width: 16px; --height: 9px; --x: -67px; --y: -118px\'></span> <span class=\'sprite-block stat-spritesheet\' style=\'--width: 16px; --height: 16px; --x: -118px; --y: -10px\'></span> +0.7 tears.',
    'wiki_link' => 'https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/The Sad Onion',
    'html' => '<span class="item-id">#1</span><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/quality/wiki-style/3.webp" class="item-quality-icon pixelated" loading="lazy"><p class="item-name">The Sad Onion</p><p class="item-description">"Tears up"</p><p class="item-pools"><span class="isaac-tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="Treasure Room<br><em>(weight: 1.0/1.0)</em>"><a href="/IsaacGuru/pools/treasure"><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/item_pools/treasure.webp" class="item-pool-icon pixelated" loading="lazy"></a></span><span class="isaac-tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="Greed Treasure Room<br><em>(weight: 1.0/1.0)</em>"><a href="/IsaacGuru/pools/greedTreasure"><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/item_pools/greedTreasure.webp" class="item-pool-icon pixelated" loading="lazy"></a></span><span class="isaac-tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="Crane Game<br><em>(weight: 1.0/1.0)</em>"><a href="/IsaacGuru/pools/craneGame"><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/item_pools/craneGame.webp" class="item-pool-icon pixelated" loading="lazy"></a></span></p><img src="data:image/webp;base64,UklGRiABAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAAQAAAAHwAAHwAAVlA4TKwAAAAvH8AHEDegpm0DJmf5oyqoRUMtJEnQhutP9Z3BKVx4AArZSIIWY9FetDM7mfkPABC/zyL98UxO4KiRJEeqZtC17j+9Q2C1CM4BOB2Cdc2fw0l1FkBE/ycA/9H5CmmaL8k3uAlgDka+wGUwZUmm4kvmkoTIzIUmLfvSKX6qUc9USkSEwqZEsDGhe+oEn8auzoRwH0t5KOAtzr0pzmtHyCRNcpKQDQ6T4AbXDP8bUFNBSU4AAAA4QklNA+0AAAAAABAASAAAAAEAAQBIAAAAAQABOEJJTQQoAAAAAAAMAAAAAj/wAAAAAAAAOEJJTQRDAAAAAAANUGJlVwEQAAUBAAAAAAA=" class="item-icon-in-description pixelated" alt="The Sad Onion"><p class="item-type">Passive item</p><hr><p class="item-contents"><span class=\'sprite-block stat-spritesheet\' style=\'--width: 16px; --height: 9px; --x: -67px; --y: -118px\'></span> <span class=\'sprite-block stat-spritesheet\' style=\'--width: 16px; --height: 16px; --x: -118px; --y: -10px\'></span> +0.7 tears.</p><hr><p class="item-tags-title">- Tags -</p><p class="item-tags"><span class="isaac-tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="<span class=\'tooltip-tag-name\'>summonable</span><hr class=\'quick-hr\'>Can be summoned via <a href=\'/IsaacGuru/item/c712\' class=\'inline-icon-link inline-block\'><img src=\'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRhgBAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAAQAAAAHwAAHwAAVlA4TKQAAAAvH8AHEDegkJEkNncI7YvI6zyZCGb2R5Oz6iEMxYwkwbkxOJ+jsTQ7/wEAwu0w9X8x3Q6c1dbbNjYDZwHwYCAfEXCO/6eLgFPxByF9nQAi+j8B7j9PKhA0b01JnYwQic5KefLAPlrNx2Q16tygISIC1c6dCzRoENa5MzRERDLSqHODaB+tYnRWeoHoM0kFJh2Ix1NEHhswqRGISTXcZHojGO4vAlBTQUlOAAAAOEJJTQPtAAAAAAAQAEgAAAABAAEASAAAAAEAAThCSU0EKAAAAAAADAAAAAI/8AAAAAAAADhCSU0EQwAAAAAADVBiZVcBEAAFAQAAAAAA\' class=\'inline-icon pixelated\'> Lemegeton</a>."><a href="/IsaacGuru/tags/summonable"><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/item_tags/summonable.webp" class="item-tag-icon pixelated" loading="lazy"></a></span><span class="isaac-tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="<span class=\'tooltip-tag-name\'>tearsup</span><hr class=\'quick-hr\'>Contributes towards unlocking <a href=\'/IsaacGuru/item/c532\' class=\'inline-icon-link inline-block\'><img src=\'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjIBAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAAQAAAAHwAAHwAAVlA4TL4AAAAvH8AHEDdAkG2zzN/tAneZBpmAxW5NxJdDqClI24Ap8y9n8t78ByA/z8gWf1kD7Eiy4zavCkrgsgOwFMArD6DvaxnBAyJQ/lHg8BlARP8nwP5zT1+BFSf5M6eRzAEuYnBTJlTY6oz4kEqUNLB8Pj+kCtbLICSppFkDts88Mo/8/toHjcnzAVwvWhCAFiK/gK1OjALHa2sLW4VoJU08Wl+eI4wB2nVOclprPEc8MHqTDSpmgE2dZEPZrjNs9i8DUFNBSU4AAAA4QklNA+0AAAAAABAASAAAAAEAAQBIAAAAAQABOEJJTQQoAAAAAAAMAAAAAj/wAAAAAAAAOEJJTQRDAAAAAAANUGJlVwEQAAUBAAAAAAA=\' class=\'inline-icon pixelated\'> Lachryphagy</a>."><a href="/IsaacGuru/tags/tearsup"><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/item_tags/tearsup.webp" class="item-tag-icon pixelated" loading="lazy"></a></span><span class="isaac-tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="<span class=\'tooltip-tag-name\'>offensive</span><hr class=\'quick-hr\'>Can appear for <b>Tainted Lost</b>."><a href="/IsaacGuru/tags/offensive"><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/item_tags/offensive.webp" class="item-tag-icon pixelated" loading="lazy"></a></span></p><p class="item-tags-title">- Links -</p><p class="item-tags"><a href="https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/The Sad Onion"><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/custom/wiki.png" class="item-tag-icon pixelated" loading="lazy"></a><p class="item-tags-title">- Costume -</p><p class="item-tags"><img src="/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/costumes/Collectible_The_Sad_Onion_appearance.webp" class="item-costume pixelated" loading="lazy"></a></p>',
    'unlock' => NULL,
    'wiki' => NULL,
    'custom_pools' => NULL,
    'chargetext' => NULL,
    'youtube' => NULL,
    'weight-bar' => 
    array (
      'treasure' => '<div class="weight-bar"><div style="--weight: 100%; --weight-color: lime"></div><center>1.0 / 1.0</center></div>',
      'greedTreasure' => '<div class="weight-bar"><div style="--weight: 100%; --weight-color: lime"></div><center>1.0 / 1.0</center></div>',
      'craneGame' => '<div class="weight-bar"><div style="--weight: 100%; --weight-color: lime"></div><center>1.0 / 1.0</center></div>',
      'zodiacBeggar' => '<div class="weight-bar"><div style="--weight: 100%; --weight-color: lime"></div><center>1.0 / 1.0</center></div>',
    ),
    'custom_gfx' => NULL,
    'guru-id' => 0,
    'custom_gfx_raw' => NULL,
    'custom_transformations' => NULL,
    'main-type' => 'item',
    'synergies_raw' => NULL,
    'synergies' => 
    array (
    ),
    'icon-size' => '1',
    'sounds' => NULL,
    'gfx-uri' => 'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRiABAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAAQAAAAHwAAHwAAVlA4TKwAAAAvH8AHEDegpm0DJmf5oyqoRUMtJEnQhutP9Z3BKVx4AArZSIIWY9FetDM7mfkPABC/zyL98UxO4KiRJEeqZtC17j+9Q2C1CM4BOB2Cdc2fw0l1FkBE/ycA/9H5CmmaL8k3uAlgDka+wGUwZUmm4kvmkoTIzIUmLfvSKX6qUc9USkSEwqZEsDGhe+oEn8auzoRwH0t5KOAtzr0pzmtHyCRNcpKQDQ6T4AbXDP8bUFNBSU4AAAA4QklNA+0AAAAAABAASAAAAAEAAQBIAAAAAQABOEJJTQQoAAAAAAAMAAAAAj/wAAAAAAAAOEJJTQRDAAAAAAANUGJlVwEQAAUBAAAAAAA=',
    'animated' => false,
    'death-icon-file' => '/IsaacGuru/core/assets/img/items/death_icons/vanilla_death_items.webp',
    'death-icon-column' => '1',
    'death-icon-row' => '1',
    'death-icon-file-raw' => 'vanilla_death_items.webp',
  ),
```

And to display this information I use a simple Ajax load directly inside the description box:

```js
$(".item-container").on("mouseover", ".item-icon-container", function()
{
    $("#desc").load(directory + "/core/includes/ajax/desc.php?item=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('itemid')), function()
});
```

desc.php:

```php
require_once('../../../core/includes/custom_data.php');
echo $itemsArray[$_GET['item']]['html'];
```

Currently everything is working fine but I'm only testing this locally on a powerful machine, and I have doubts about its performance on an actual hosted website, especially since the PHP array file currently sits at 15 MB with nearly 100.000 lines of code.

1. Would it be better to use JSON and load the entire file directly in JS when the page loads, or pull from a JSON array via Ajax, or some other Ajax method?
2. Is caching the HTML code a good idea or should I just pass the smaller details and do all the formatting directly in the JS script?
3. Is it better to use data URI for displaying small icons, especially when there can be a lot of them on a single mouse hover (up to 50 at most), or should I just use a normal "src" path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Better" is always subjective. Whatever you do, part of your decision should be based on maintenance. Storing as much as you are talking about only in PHP would arguably be very complicated to debug and refactor. For me, this is where a database would come in, although there's other ways. After that, then possibly a build script to generate "something". If you go down this path, I'm not seeing a reason for "something" being PHP, actually, it could be HTML or JS because it is only needed for client-side data.

Comment: Your AJAX approach is good, don't let the user load 15 MB into their browser when only a small part of that is needed. I also think that a database is a better place to store 15 MB of data. Whether that will be faster? I'm not so sure. Probably.... but it is just a more standard way of dealing with this amount of data. Databases have a lot of extra features that a flat array doesn't have. Some day you will need those features.

Comment: @ChrisHaas the PHP array is automatically generated by reading .xml files, and I have created an entire admin panel where I manually input some of the data that cannot be handled automatically, i.e. the custom description. So maintenance is not what I'm worried about here as the admin panel handles all of that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I was thinking about an SQL database too, but I think that reading from a local file would be faster than accessing a server, or maybe I'm wrong? Since I already made an entire admin panel to manage the array and all of its keys, I think I'm going to stick with a local file for now. Just wanted to know whether I can improve its performance by switching to a different type of array/file.

Comment: It is rather difficult to predict how performant something will be until you really try it, and even then it might heavily depend on the configuration of your system. To me it doesn't sound right to have a PHP file with a 15 MB array in it, but since I've never tried it, I cannot guess how it will perform. I think a database will perform pretty well. You could [start with a SQLite database in a file using PDO](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/web/php/snippets/sqlite/index). That way you don't need a "database server", and it would be easy to change the code when you do get one.

Comment: @OciXCrom, thanks, I'm glad you've got a good admin interface, a lot of people miss that as it relates to "performance". Looking at your sample, about 60% of the text lives under the "html" key. If that could be optimized, possibly into JS, that's be significant savings alone. I think you might have to per-test this in the real world ultimately. Maybe build a quick loader with a progress bar, and you could test 2000 calls, 1 giant call, and maybe 20 smaller calls. This load will partly be about perception and not true performance, too.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware, I will give your method a try, and maybe some others as well in order to make a comparison and settle for the most optimal result.